# Using input args inside a TaskKey

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing an sbt plugin, and have created a TaskKey that need to get parsed arguments

```
  lazy val getManager = TaskKey[DeployManager]("Deploy manager")
  lazy val getCustomConfig = InputKey[String]("Custom config")
  ...

  getCustomConfig := {
    spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed(0)
  }
  getManager := {
  val conf = configResource.evaluated
  ...

  }
```

but I get this error during compilation:

```
`parsed` can only be used within an input task macro, such as := or Def.inputTask.
```

I can't define `getManager` as `InputKey` since I later use it's value many times, and for an `inputKey` the value gets created anew on each evaluation (and I need to use the same instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want in a reasonable way in sbt. (And the type system nicely prevents you from doing that in this case).

Imagine that `getManager` is a `TaskKey` that takes parsed arguments (a note aside, the sbt way of naming this would probably be `manager`, `get` is implied).

I now decide that, for example, `compile` depends on `getManager`. If I type `compile` in the shell, what arguments should `getManager` parse?

There is no concept of arguments inside the sbt dependency tree. They are just a shallow (and IMHO somewhat hackish) addition to make for a nicer CLI.

If you want to make `getManager` configurable, you can add additional settings, `getManager` depends on and then use `set` on the command line to change these where necessary.

So in you case:

```
lazy val configResource = SettingKey[...]("Config resource")

getManager := {
  val conf = configResource.value
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.
I defined ```configResource``` as ```Option[String]``` (with default value ```None```), and running the sbt with ```sbt "set every configResource := Some(\"xxx.conf\") " my_plugin```